# How do I change the time zone in interactive brokers?

Tags: java, timezone, interactive-brokers, tws

I am using the Interactive Brokers API, TWS release 974, with IBC and the ib_insync library. I would like to change the time zone inside one of these, in order to get market data and history according to the America/New_York time zone. I have already changed the machine's time zone to the needed one, but this has no effect on the IB results. Where can I make the change to get the proper time zone?

Comment: Searching for "time zone" or "timezone" in [the API docs](https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/) gives lots of results.  Do none of these help?  Also, it would help if you could edit your question to show the code you are running, so we know which particular parts of the API you are using.

Answer (score 15):

Based on InteractiveBrokers Live Chat:

By default the TWS clock is synchronized with your local PC operating system time zone.

It is possible to change your TWS time zone at the moment you log in to TWS: click on More options at the bottom left corner of the TWS login screen.

[image]

then click on Time Zone. button to choose your TWS time zone and click OK. Then enter User name and Password and click on Login.

[image]

Comment: How to change the same of IOS app.
the More options button does seem to be present in the IOS APP.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: patz. It seems no such time zone option in IOS app.

Comment: thanks for replying, yeah I searched a lot couldnt figure out.

Comment: most likely I think I should just reach out the IB customer center for this. Most likely they won't have an answer either, but atleast they can provide to the feedback to the dev team.